# Why the coefficient estimates of glmnet varies a lot between models with same input parameters?

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

I have been trying to fit a lasso model using `cv.glmnet`. I tried to implement four different models (3 using `cv.glmnet` and 1 using `caret::train`) based on standardization. All the four models give very different coefficient estimates which I can't figure out why.

Here is a fully reproducible code:

```
library("glmnet")
data(iris)
iris <- iris
dat <- iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"),]
X <- as.matrix(dat[,1:4])
Y <- as.factor(as.character(dat$Species))

set.seed(123)
model1 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,
                    y = Y,
                    family = "binomial",
                    standardize = FALSE,
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                    nfolds = 3)

set.seed(123)
model2 <- cv.glmnet(x = scale(X, center = T, scale = T),
                    y = Y,
                    family = "binomial",
                    standardize = FALSE,
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                    nfolds = 3)
set.seed(123)
model3 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,
                    y = Y,
                    family = "binomial",
                    standardize = TRUE,
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                    nfolds = 3)

##Using caret
library("caret")

lambda.grid <- rev(seq(0,1,length=100)) #set of lambda values for cross-validation
alpha.grid <- 1 #alpha
trainControl <- trainControl(method ="cv",
                             number=3) #3-fold cross-validation
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.alpha=alpha.grid, .lambda=lambda.grid) #these are tuning parameters to be passed into the train function below

set.seed(123)
model4 <- train(x = X,
                y = Y,
                method="glmnet",
                family="binomial",
                standardize = FALSE,
                trControl = trainControl,                          
                tuneGrid = tuneGrid)

c1 <- coef(model1, s=model1$lambda.min)
c2 <- coef(model2, s=model2$lambda.min)
c3 <- coef(model3, s=model3$lambda.min)
c4 <- coef(model4$finalModel, s=model4$finalModel$lambdaOpt)
c1 <- as.matrix(c1)
c2 <- as.matrix(c2)
c3 <- as.matrix(c3)
c4 <- as.matrix(c4)
```

`model2` scales the independent variables (vector `X`) beforehand and `model3` does so by setting `standardize = TRUE`. So atleast these two models should return identical results - but it is not so.

The lambda.min obtained from the four models are:

```
model1 = 0

model2 = 0

model3 = 0

model4 = 0.6565657
```

The coefficient estimates between the models differ drastically too. Why would this be occurring?

Comment: The standardization by `glmnet` is done by the fortran code underneath, so it is hard to judge whether that and `scale` are actually 100% doing the same thing.

Comment: Regardless of the underneath programming language used, scale should standardize the data. This means substracting each column values by their corresponding column means and dividing the column standard deviation to have unit variance and zero mean. Can't quite understand why things should be so complicated when it shouldn't be :-(

Comment: For comparison c2 to c3: at the `?glmnet` `standardize` argument ; when TRUE... *"The coefficients are always returned on the original scale.*, this will not happen when you have manually transformed. So you can transform back to original scale manually: `xs = scale(X) ; 
sx = attr(xs, "scaled:scale") ; ce = attr(xs, "scaled:center") ; co = as.numeric(c2) ; co[-1] / sx ; co[1] - sum((co[-1] / sx)*sx)` - which are much closeer

Comment: I haven't tested out what you said. Your comment does make sense to me. Thanks for that. But then the question of the moment is why model1 and model3 are outputting different estimates of coefficients? model1 does not standardize the data, model 3 does, but as per documentation, the coefficients are returned in original scale. Can't correlate these findings to what the documentation of glmnet says

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a little different between `scale(x) & standardize = FALSE` and `x & standardize = TRUE`. We need to multiple (N-1)/N.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155362/glmnet-unstandardizing-linear-regression-coefficients).

If we use gaussian family,

```
library(glmnet)
X <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 1), ncol=2)
y <- 1 -2*X[,1] + X[,2]

enet <- glmnet(X, y, lambda=0.1,standardize = T,family="gaussian")
coefficients(enet)
coef <- coefficients(enet)
coef[2]*sd(X[,1])/sd(y) #standardized coef
#[1] -0.6895065

enet1 <- glmnet(scale(X)/99*100, y/(99/100*sd(y)),lambda=0.1/(99/100*sd(y)),standardize = F,family="gaussian")
coefficients(enet1)[2]
#[1] -0.6894995
```

If we use binomial family,

```
data(iris)
iris <- iris
dat <- iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"),]
X <- as.matrix(dat[,1:4])
Y <- as.factor(as.character(dat$Species))

set.seed(123)
model1 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,
                y = Y,
                family = "binomial",
                standardize = T,
                alpha = 1,
                lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                nfolds = 3)
coefficients(model1,s=0.03)[3]*sd(X[,2])
#[1] -0.3374946

set.seed(123)
model3 <- cv.glmnet(x = scale(X)/99*100,
                y = Y,
                family = "binomial",
                standardize = F,
                alpha = 1,
                lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                nfolds = 3)
coefficients(model3,s=0.03)[3]
#[1] -0.3355027
```

These results are nearly the same. Hope it is not too late for this answer.